# php openid connect get token

Tags: php, token, jwt, openid-connect

I try to use [jumbojett](https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP) library for php and openid. I made connection but and get secret id and client, but when I want to get token I don't know how.

In small documentation is next example:

```
$oidc = new OpenIDConnectClient('https://id.provider.com',
                                'ClientIDHere',
                                'ClientSecretHere');
$oidc->providerConfigParam(array('token_endpoint'=>'https://id.provider.com/connect/token'));
$oidc->addScope('my_scope');

// this assumes success (to validate check if the access_token property is there and a valid JWT) :
$clientCredentialsToken = $oidc->requestClientCredentialsToken()->access_token;
```

But function `requestClientCredentialsToken()` doesn't exist in library. Does anyone know how to get token or to recommend some another php library where I can define scope, redirect uri, get client secret and id from open server and offcourse to get token.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also when I use $this->oidc->authenticate(); I get login page from auth service, and when I login and go to redirect uri I have too many redirection and my app die. Does anyone know solution fot this problem?

Comment: You should probably have two pieces of code - one that creates an authentication URL and sends a redirect response, another one that handles the redirect from OAuth2 server. You cannot request a token synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

There is a public function `getAccessToken()`.
You should modify the the code above like this:

```
$oidc = new OpenIDConnectClient('https://id.provider.com',
                            'ClientIDHere',
                            'ClientSecretHere');
$oidc->providerConfigParam(array('token_endpoint'=>'https://id.provider.com/connect/token'));
$oidc->addScope('my_scope');

$oicd->authenticate();
$mytoken=$oidc->getAccessToken();
```